# form a list of list by filtering columns of panda.merge output in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, merge

I have merged two csv files using pandas and have saved the merged output in `merged` variable using:

```
merged= pd.merge(f1,f2,on='name',how='inner')
```

This `merged` has about 10 columns and I want to select two colmuns - `name` and `type`, from it and form a `list of lists`, the output of which should be something like in this format:

```
         [['Bread', 'Milk'],
         ['Bread', 'Diapers', 'Beer', 'Eggs'],
         ['Milk', 'Diapers', 'Beer', 'Coke'],
         ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Diapers', 'Beer'],
         ['Bread', 'Milk', 'Diapers', 'Coke']]
```

Here, the fist values inside each inner list should be `name` followed by values of `type` which can be multiples in which case they all are separated by `,`.

I do not know how can I filter out the two columns from merged output of pandas merge above and form the list of lists form those two columns like above format?

Comment: Does the Type column currently contain one string (with multiple words being comma-separate), or a lists of strings?

Comment: @selllikesybok it contains one string with multiple words being comma-separated

Answer (score 0):

I've never directly used pandas, but assuming the output of accessing columns is a `list`, this should work:

```
listoflists = [[n]+t.split(',') for n,t in zip(merged.name,merged.type)]
```

That `zip` outputs a list of tuples that is almost what you want, except you need to split the strings from `type` if they contain more than one item.

For each tuple in that list, the outer list comprehension wraps the name value `n` tuple in a list, splits the type string `t` on any `,`s (output of `str.split` is a list, which is why `n` gets wrapped), and adds those two lists together.